# Can you write async tests that expect toThrow?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm writing an async test that expects the async function to throw like this:

```
it("expects to have failed", async () => {
  let getBadResults = async () => {
    await failingAsyncTest()
  }
  expect(await getBadResults()).toThrow()
})
```

But jest is just failing instead of passing the test:

```
 FAIL  src/failing-test.spec.js
  ● expects to have failed

    Failed: I should fail!
```

If I rewrite the test to looks like this:

```
expect(async () => {
  await failingAsyncTest()
}).toThrow()
```

I get this error instead of a passing test:

```
expect(function).toThrow(undefined)

Expected the function to throw an error.
But it didn't throw anything.
```

Answer (score 889, accepted):

You can test your async function like this:

```
it('should test async errors', async () =>  {        
    await expect(failingAsyncTest())
    .rejects
    .toThrow('I should fail');
});
```

'I should fail' string will match any part of the error thrown.

Comment: This is now documented in https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#rejects

Comment: Actually has issues, documented example fails. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3601 has workarounds including `await expect(failingAsyncTest()).rejects.toHaveProperty('message', 'I should fail');`

Comment: @Lisandro This code doesn't work. Yes, the unit test passes, but not because `failingAsyncTest` threw the right kind of error. It's more obvious if you change the implementation of `failingAsyncTest` to throw _the wrong error_ instead of the right one. (using Jest 23.6)

Comment: @Tom The solution never claims to match the error **Type**. It clearly states the string matches de error **Message**. It works perfectly fine. Best.

Comment: It's more obvious that toThrow tests for a substring if you change its parameter to a RegExp: `await expect(failingAsyncTest()).rejects.toThrow(/fail/);`

Comment: Make sure to add `await` or `return`  before `expect`, otherwise the test will always pass even if it does not throw

Comment: What is the difference between expect(promise).rejects.toMatch(error) and expect(promise).rejects.toThrow(error). Shouldn't rejects unwrap the actual error? Then, this would not make sense (or doesn't make sense to me) -> expect(error).toThrow(error).  There is an example for toMatch with rejects here: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait

Comment: If anyone is interested, the updated documentation is here: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects

Comment: I know you could be here if your async function takes input (params) and now how do you do that

```js
expect(async () => await asyncFuncWithParam(params)).rejects.toThrow(MyError);
```

Answer (score 105):

I'd like to just add on to this and say that the function you're testing must throw an actual Error object `throw new Error(...)`. Jest does not seem to recognize if you just throw an expression like `throw 'An error occurred!'`.

Comment: Well you just saved me a boatload of time.

Comment: is there any workaround if we are to keep `throw 'an error'`?

Comment: I am wrapping the function that should throw in a try catch in the tests. And then in the catch block I can do `expect(error).toMatchObject(expectedError)` but it looks quite dodgy

Comment: Apparently this also doesn't work with custom errors that inherit from Error :(

Comment: so glad you posted this - i was throwing an error that i thought was already an Error obj but the test kept failing. added this and good to go.

Comment: @mikey `await expect(failingAsyncTest()).rejects.toBe('an error')`

Answer (score 47):

```
await expect(async () => { 
    await someAsyncFunction(someParams); 
}).rejects.toThrowError("Some error message");
```

We must wrap the code in a function to catch the error. Here we are expecting the Error message thrown from someAsyncFunction should be equal to "Some error message". We can call the exception handler also

```
await expect(async () => { 
    await someAsyncFunction(someParams); 
}).rejects.toThrowError(new InvalidArgumentError("Some error message"));
```

Read more https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

Comment: You can do this more simply with `await expect(someAsyncFunction(someParams)).rejects.toThrowError(...)`.

Comment: @Marc if I don't add `async` inside, my test doesn't get any status - not a PASS and not a FAIL. The solution in this answer however, makes the test marked as PASS.

Comment: `expect(() => someAsyncFunction())` may not work, but `expect(someAsyncFunction())` should work since the value passed to `expect()` in that case is a Promise. `expect()` will await and test its resolved value.

Answer (score 27):

**Custom Error Class**

The use of `rejects.toThrow` will not work for you. Instead, you can combine the `rejects` method with the `toBeInstanceOf` matcher to match the custom error that has been thrown.

**Example**

```js
it("should test async errors", async () => {
  await expect(asyncFunctionWithCustomError()).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(
    CustomError
  )
})
```

Answer (score 14):

To be able to make many tests conditions without having to resolve the promise every time, this will also work:

```js
it('throws an error when it is not possible to create an user', async () => {
        const throwingFunction = () => createUser(createUserPayload)

        // This is what prevents the test to succeed when the promise is resolved and not rejected
        expect.assertions(3)

        await throwingFunction().catch(error => {
            expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(Error)
            expect(error.message).toMatch(new RegExp('Could not create user'))
            expect(error).toMatchObject({
                details: new RegExp('Invalid payload provided'),
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: You can also write `throwingFunction.then(() => done('should have rejected'), error => { .... make assertions ... })`.  ("done" is an argument to the spec callback.)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to test that an async function does NOT throw:

```
it('async function does not throw', async () => {
    await expect(hopefullyDoesntThrow()).resolves.not.toThrow();
});
```

The above test will pass regardless of the value returned, even if undefined.

Keep in mind that if an `async` function throws an Error, its really coming back as a **Promise Rejection** in Node, not an error (thats why if you don't have try/catch blocks you will get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`, slightly different than an error). So, like others have said, that is why you use either:

1. `.rejects` and `.resolves` methods, or a
2. `try/catch` block within your tests.

Reference:
https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#asyncawait

Answer (score 7):

I've been testing for Firebase cloud functions and this is what I came up with:

```
test("It should test async on failing cloud functions calls", async () => {
    await expect(async ()=> {
        await failingCloudFunction(params)
    })
    .rejects
    .toThrow("Invalid type"); // This is the value for my specific error
  });
```

This is built on top of [lisandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887098/8840456).

Comment: This is the only code worked for me, but I completely don't understand why do I need to wrap a promise with a function to catch thrown error with Jest. It just feels it should work out of the box without it.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
it("expects to have failed", async () => {
  let getBadResults = async () => {
    await failingAsyncTest()
  }
  expect(getBadResults()).reject.toMatch('foo')
  // or in my case
  expect(getBadResults()).reject.toMatchObject({ message: 'foo' })
})
```

Comment: This answer deserves huge credit. Its the one that catches the cases such as `throw "some_string"` instead of `throw Error()`

Answer (score -1):

You can do like below if you want to use the try/catch method inside the test case.

```
test("some test case name with success", async () => {
 let response = null;
 let failure = null;
  // Before calling the method, make sure someAsyncFunction should be succeeded
 try {
  response = await someAsyncFunction();
 } catch(err) {
  error = err;
 }
expect(response).toEqual(SOME_MOCK_RESPONSE)
expect(error).toBeNull();
})

test("some test case name with failure", async () => {
 let response = null;
 let error = null;
 // Before calling the method, make sure someAsyncFunction should throw some error by mocking in proper way
 try {
  response = await someAsyncFunction();
 } catch(err) {
  error = err;
 }
expect(response).toBeNull();
expect(error).toEqual(YOUR_MOCK_ERROR)
})
```

**Edit:**

As my given solution is not taking the advantage of inbuilt jest tests with the throwing feature, please do follow the other solution suggested by @Lisandro https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887098/8988448

```
it('should test async errors', async () =>  {        
    await expect(failingAsyncTest())
    .rejects
    .toThrow('I should fail');
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
test("It should test async on failing cloud functions calls", async (done) => {
   failingCloudFunction(params).catch(e => {
    expect(e.message).toBe('Invalid type');
    done()
   })
  });
```

Comment: This test won't fail if `failingCloudFunction` does not throw an error. It only tests the error message. Not a good real life example.