# Jest toThrow() method not capturing error

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am doing this:

```
expect(async () => {await doSomething()}).toThrow('myThrownErrorMessage');
```

but this throws an error in the terminal:

> (node:12725) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 575): Error: myThrownErrorMessage

Is this simply a case of node capturing the error before Jest does?

Comment: This should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144187/can-you-write-async-tests-that-expect-tothrow