# How to assert an async method throwing Error using toThrow with Jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144187/can-you-write-async-tests-that-expect-tothrow) which expects a `Promise` to work. In my case the `Error` is thrown before and outside a `Promise`.

How can I assert the error in this case? I have tried the options below.

```
test('Method should throw Error', async () => {

    let throwThis = async () => {
        throw new Error();
    };

    await expect(throwThis).toThrow(Error);
    await expect(throwThis).rejects.toThrow(Error);
});
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Calling `throwThis` returns a `Promise` that should reject with an `Error` so the syntax should be:

```js
test('Method should throw Error', async () => {

  let throwThis = async () => {
    throw new Error();
  };

  await expect(throwThis()).rejects.toThrow(Error);  // SUCCESS
});
```

Note that `toThrow` was fixed for promises in [PR 4884](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4884) and [only works in 21.3.0+](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4884#discussion_r150754390).

So *this will only work* if you are using `Jest` version 22.0.0 or higher.

---

If you are using an earlier version of `Jest` you can pass a `spy` to `catch`:

```js
test('Method should throw Error', async () => {

  let throwThis = async () => {
    throw new Error();
  };

  const spy = jest.fn();
  await throwThis().catch(spy);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

...and optionally check the `Error` thrown [by checking `spy.mock.calls[0][0]`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls).

Comment: (just an addition) `await expect(throwThis()).rejects.toEqual(expect.any(Error));` works too(I believe even for older `jest`)

Comment: Thank you! I'm using latest (24.1), so the first example worked.

Comment: @Darlesson you're welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!

Comment: @skyboyer nice, that's really clean.  As long as you don't need to check for any details about the `Error` that is a nice way to do it and I just verified that it works back to at least version 20.0.4.

Comment: For some reason the first example always gave me a "correct" test. It never failed, even when it should. I opted for the second one and it worked.