# How to mock non-async method for throwing an exception with Jest?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Here is a fragment from my code in TypeScript:

```
let myService: MyService;
let myController: MyController;

beforeAll(async function () {
    myService = new MyService(null);
    myController = new MyController(myService);
});

it("should fail due to any 'MyService' error", () => {
    jest.spyOn(myService, 'create').mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new Error(); // ! the test fails here
    });
    expect(myController.create(data)).toThrowError(Error);
});
```

The `create` method of `MyController` *is not async*, neither is of `MyService`: both are just regular methods. Now when I try to run this test it fails on the line of the mocked method where the exception is thrown: `throw new Error()` and it works correctly only if I wrap the `create` method call with `try/catch` like this:

```
try {
    expect(myController.create(data)).toThrowError(Error);
}
catch { }
```

It looks very strange to me. Shouldn't it work without wrapping in `try/catch` by design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a small change.

---

From the [`.toThrowError` doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror):

> Use `.toThrowError` to test that a function throws when it is called.

---

You are passing *the result of calling* `myController.create(data)`.

You need to pass *a function that throws when it is called*, in this case:

```js
() => { myController.create(data); }
```

---

Change your `expect` line to this:

```js
expect(() => { myController.create(data); }).toThrowError(Error);  // SUCCESS
```

...and it should work.

Comment: So, if we pass there an async function that actually means that we pass a `Promise` wrapper which is managed then by Jest and that's why we don't need to wrap it in another function anymore as in this case (with sync method)?

Comment: @Sergey yes, testing that an `async` function throws an `Error` is really just testing that it returns a `Promise` that rejects with the `Error`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585620/10149510) for more details