# Jest - assert async function throws test fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Got the following failing test case and i'm not sure why:

**foo.js**

```
async function throws() {
  throw 'error';
}

async function foo() {
  try {
    await throws();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

**test.js**

```
const foo = require('./foo');

describe('foo', () => {
  it('should log and rethrow', async () => {
    await expect(foo()).rejects.toThrow();
  });
});
```

I expect foo to throw but for some reason it just resolves and the test fails:

`FAILED foo › should log and rethrow - Received function did not throw`

[Live example](https://repl.it/repls/LopsidedDeafeningPattern)

Probably missing some basic detail of async await throw behavior.

Comment: don't await it ... just `expect(foo()).rejects.toThrow();` = because all foo does is return a promise that rejects ...

Comment: @Bravo that's just hiding the problem because the test doesn't wait for the result.

Comment: yeah, I see that ... but wouldn't you expect( await foo()) instead? I'm getting dizzy :p

Comment: @Bravo yeah it's quite confusing but that's the way to test a throwing async function :) [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887098/4341456](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47887098/4341456)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you need is to check the rejected error

```js
const foo = require('./foo');
describe('foo', () => {
  it('should log and rethrow', async () => {
    await expect(foo()).rejects.toEqual('error');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, not 100% sure it the same as testing for throwing but i guess it's the next best thing.
Ended up going with `await expect(foo()).rejects.toBeTruthy();`

Comment: You can also tweak your code to something like and should work:

`async function throws() {
  throw  new Error('error');
}`

Comment: thank you! for some reason throwing errors manually requires different syntax

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's a known bug: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1700

This works though:

```
describe('foo', () => {
  it('should log and rethrow', async () => {
    await expect(foo()).rejects.toEqual('error')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code when I don't want to use `toEqual` or `toBe` (like the other correct answers). Instead, I use `toBeTruthy`.

```
async foo() {
  throw "String error";
}

describe('foo', () => {
  it('should throw a statement', async () => {
    await expect(foo()).rejects.toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```