# Async test to throw with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, try-catch

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to find a way to throw an error with an async function.

Here's the test file

```
import Yelp from './Yelp';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

describe('testing searchRestaurantsInfo', () => {

  // Other tests

  test('returns error', async () => {
    await expect(
      Yelp.searchRestaurantsInfo('q_IoMdeM57U70GwqjXxGJw')
    ).rejects.toThrow('Error');
  });
});
```

I get the error

```
testing searchRestaurantsInfo › returns error

    expect(received).rejects.toThrow()

    Received promise resolved instead of rejected
    Resolved to value: "Error"

      102 | 
      103 |   test('returns error', async () => {
    > 104 |     await expect(
          |           ^
      105 |       Yelp.searchRestaurantsInfo('q_IoMdeM57U70GwqjXxGJw')
      106 |     ).rejects.toThrow(TypeError);
      107 |   });
```

And here's Yelp.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

let YELP_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_YELP_API_KEY;

const Yelp = {
  // Provides info about a single restaurant
  async searchRestaurantsInfo(id) {
    try {
      let response = await axios.get(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/${id}`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
        }
      );

      let responseRew = await axios.get(
        `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/${id}/reviews`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${YELP_API_KEY}`,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
        }
      );

      const parameters = {
        name: response.data.name,
        address: response.data.location.display_address[0],
        coordinates: {
          lat: response.data.coordinates.latitude,
          lng: response.data.coordinates.longitude,
        },
        city: response.data.location.display_address[1],
        rating: response.data.rating,
        photos: response.data.photos,
        phone: response.data.phone,
        price: response.data.price,
        categories: response.data.categories[0].title,
        url: response.data.url,
        reviews: responseRew.data.reviews,
      };

      return parameters;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return 'Error';
    }
  },
}
```

I've been looking for a solution, and actually the one I came up with comes from here: [Can you write async tests that expect toThrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144187/can-you-write-async-tests-that-expect-tothrow)
but it's not working for me and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is directly tied to the comment from your previous question. If you expect an error to be thrown, don't catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're mocking `axios.get` to reject before you assert a promise rejection in your test, there's an issue in `Yelp.js` in the catch block. You need to rethrow the error:

```
catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      throw e;
}
```

In case you haven't mocked axios to throw an error, add this before you call the function:

```
axios.get.mockRejectedValue('error');
```

Let me know if this worked for you.