# Is it possible to check that a set of statements in test shouldn't be called in Jest

Tags: jestjs

Is it possible to test that a code path is not executed in a test case in Jest?

For example, in the following test, I want the `then` part to execute (which has an `expect` but I don't want the `catch` part to execute.)

Will Jest automatically fail the test if `catch` part is hit and it can't find an `expect` in it?

```js
describe('Endpoints are accessible', () => {
  it('GET request for homepage should return 200', async () => {
    const baseURL = process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST
    console.log(`base url is ${baseURL}`)

    const req = {}

    const res = {}

    indexControllerModule
      .homepageHandler(req, res)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(`result is ${result}`)
        expect(result).toBe(
          JSON.stringify({
            message: 'welcome',
          })
        )
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(
          `This code path shouldn't be executed. Error in accessing homepage: ${error}`
        )
      })
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove `.catch`.

Assuming your timeout is long enough the promise will either resolve (`.then`) or reject (`.catch`). If rejected the promise will throw an error which is treated as a failed test by jest. But by catching the rejected promise you prevent the test from failing.

Comment: Thanks. Would it work the other way as well. i.e. the test should fail so I should have a `catch`, not `then`?

Comment: in that case you can use jest `await expect(functionCall()).rejects.toThrow()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47144187/can-you-write-async-tests-that-expect-tothrow