# How can I check the type of the error thrown asyncronously in Jest?

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
const f = async () => {
  throw new Error('Huh???!');
};
```

And I want to test that it throws a `RangeError` (not just an `Error`) using Jest.

```
test('f throws a RangeError', () => {
  expect(f()).rejects.toThrowError(RangeError);
});
```

However this test passes.

How can I check the type of the error thrown asyncronously in Jest?

Comment: I don't know if I'm right but you may try to `await f()` within a try/catch and in the catch check the `typeof` the error.

Comment: That is one option, but `rejects` is meant to do the `await`ing

Comment: I just found that https://stackoverflow.com/q/46042613/1985912.

Comment: That is not `async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `toBeInstanceOf` matcher after `rejects`:

```
test('f throws a RangeError', () => {
  expect(f()).rejects.toBeInstanceOf(RangeError);
});
```