# Testing for typed exceptions with Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

[Attempting to utilize the approach outlined in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042613/how-to-test-type-of-thrown-exception-in-jest).

I have the following typed exception:

```
    /**
     * @param message The error message
     * @param value The value that violates the constraint
     * @param field The name of the field
     * @param type The expected type for the field
     * @param code The application or module code for the error
     */
    export class IsError extends Error {
      constructor(
        public message:string,
        public value: any, 
        public field:string, 
        public type: string,
        public code?:string) {
          super(message);
          this.name = 'IsError';
      }
    }
```

This function throws it:

```
 export function isBooleanError(value: any, field:string, code?: string): void {
      if (!isBoolean(value)) {
        const message:string = `The field ${field} should be a boolean valued.  It is set to ${value}. `;
        throw new IsError(message, value, field, BOOLEAN_TYPE, code);
      }
    }
```

This works:

```
expect(()=>{isBooleanError({}, '')}).toThrow(Error);
```

But this does not:

```
expect(()=>{isBooleanError({}, '')}).toThrow(IsError);
```

Anyone know why the latter does not work? Jest logs:

```
expect(received).toThrow(expected)

Expected name: "IsError"
Received name: "Error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to the constructor of the exception:

```
  super(message);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, IsError.prototype);
```

Comment: And you need this to make `instanceof` work with subclasses of `Error`: see [#13965](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965)

Comment: Excellent point ... Is there some final recommendation of this.  I read through the link, but it seems it was a bit up in the air.  Would be nice to be able to use `instanceof`.  Jest is able to check that the exception thrown is a `IsError`.  Do you know what type of check it uses?

Comment: Asked follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55065742/implementing-instanceof-checks-for-custom-typescript-errors