# Implementing instanceof checks for custom typescript Error instances?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

Typescript has this [instanceof checks on custom errors](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965) issue, but it's not clear what we need to do to get `instanceof` working.  For example for this exception how would we get `instanceof` working:

```
    /**
     * @param message The error message
     * @param value The value that violates the constraint
     * @param field The name of the field
     * @param type The expected type for the field
     * @param constraint The name of the constraint violated
     * @param code The application or module code for the error
     */
    export class IsError extends Error {
      constructor(
        public message:string,
        public value: any, 
        public field?:string, 
        public type?: string,
        public constraint?: string,
        public code?:string) {
          super(message);
          this.name = 'IsError';
          Object.setPrototypeOf(this, IsError.prototype);      
      }
    }
```

[This link says we can manually adjust the prototype](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work), which is what I'm doing, but this test is not passing:

```
it("should be an instance of IsError", () => {
   let error = new IsError("This is an IsError", 'value');
   expect(error instanceof IsError)).toBeTruthy();
});
```

### Correction

I had an additional parenthesis in the test `...IsError))` that I mistook for the test not passing.  I updated the test and now it work.  So the example `IsError` implementation in this question is correct.

IIUC this implementation will not not work in ES5, but AFAIK clients that include CoreJS will be ok.

Comment: What happens when you don't extend the Error class and instead only rely on the `Object.setPrototypeOf` line?

Comment: Tried it - The check test still does not pass ...

Comment: I created a basic example ([here](https://pastebin.com/fN8Mmx17)) which does work for me. I use Typescript 3.0.1.

Comment: Duh ... Thank you for pointing this out - I had an additional parenthesis in my jest test that made it appear as if the test was not passing.  It's all good now.  Example is simpler.  Please post it as the answer and I'll check it off.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What goes wrong in your code (as you correctly pointed out) was an extra parenthesis in your assertion.

Just to be complete, a working and minimal example would look like this:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super();

        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, CustomError.prototype);
    }
}

let error = new CustomError();

console.log(error instanceof CustomError); // Will log 'true'
```

Comment: If you try to extend `CustomError`, you will need to do the same with `constructor()`.

Comment: In this case, the `constructor()` is not extending the base implementation, for example: try to do `new CustomError('Test').message`...

Comment: Thanks a **million**. Surprisingly not present in higher ranking tutorials, ChatGPT wasn't able to crack it either.

Answer (score 14):

Read https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work

Now, a complete implementation of [@Mathyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066358/717267) and [@TmTron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066280/717267) answers:

```
/**
 * Base Error.
 */
class BaseError extends Error {
  constructor(message?: string) {
    const trueProto = new.target.prototype;
    super(message);
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, trueProto);
  }
}

class Err1 extends BaseError {}
const e1 = new Err1();
console.log(e1 instanceof Err1); // true
console.log(e1 instanceof Error); // true

class Err2 extends Err1 {}
const e2 = new Err2();
console.log(e2 instanceof Err1); // true
console.log(e2 instanceof Err2); // true
console.log(e2 instanceof Error); // true

class NoBaseErr extends Error {}
const x = new NoBaseErr();
console.log(x instanceof Error); // true
console.log(x instanceof NoBaseErr); // false !!!
```

### Package

```
import BaseError from 'ts-base-error';
```

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-base-error

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `Object.setPrototypeOf()` required **es6** - [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf#Specifications)

This code from [TypeScript#13965](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965#issuecomment-278570200) works for me (in **es5**)

```
export class MyError extends Error {
    __proto__: Error;
    constructor(message?: string) {
        const trueProto = new.target.prototype;
        super(message);

        // Alternatively use Object.setPrototypeOf if you have an ES6 environment.
        this.__proto__ = trueProto;
    }
}
```