# rejects.toThrow in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have created this class:

```
export class ErrorList  {

  
    public HostelNotFoundError(details: ErrorDetail): FunctionalError {
        return new FunctionalError('1', 'Can\'t find this hostel', details);
    }
```

and in the service:

```
throw new ErrorList().HostelNotFoundError({} });
```

I would like to know if in Jest is possible to do something like:

```
rejects.toThrow(HostelNotFoundError);
```

Comment: isn't the actual thrown error `FunctionalError ` ?
take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042613/how-to-test-type-of-thrown-exception-in-jest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HostelNotFoundError` is not of type `FunctionalError`, it is a *method* of the `ErrorList` class that returns a new instance of `FunctionalError`. So in your unit-test you have to use:

```
rejects.toThrow(FunctionalError);
```

Note that you can use `toMatch` to validate e.g. the error-message or `toMatchObject` to validate the error's properties:

```
rejects.toMatch('Can\'t find this hostel');
```